# Server is not showing proper values

Tags: php

I have a list of ip addresses which i need to convert it into long i.e `ip2long` method...

I have used this method..

```
$ip = ip2long(trim($_REQUEST['ip']));
echo $ip;
```

It showing correct result in localhost suppose..

190.0.14.11   ----->    -1107292661

200.68.9.90   ----->     -935065254

There r many rows.. i'm showing just two example

but when ever i'm running the same code in server, it produces different result...

like

190.0.14.11   ----->     3187674635

200.68.9.90   ----->     3359902042

I can't identify the problem.

Comment: Try using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] instead. I tested this and something is mightily strange.

Comment: @NeilMasters This only retrieve its only IP address.

Comment: I'm not examining my own ip... I have to examine list of addresses through an input form...

Comment: Ahhhh I understand now. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: so can any body explain what the problem... How will i get a correct ip (long) address.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert the negative (signed) value to an unsigned value:

```
$ipstr = "190.0.14.11";
$iplong = sprintf('%u', ip2long($ipstr));
```